# TcpListener socket data getting lost due to delay in readuing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets

I am working on a GPS vehicle tracking project . Here the device used to send Latitude and Longitude signals to a particular IP (Static IP) on the port 5000. There are 17 devices in total.

My problem is when all the 17 device are activated I am not getting the readings from all device in a proper time duration. This means if I got the readings of Device 1 I will continuously get 5 to 6 readings from that device after that when Device 2 I will continuously get 5 to 6 readings similarly it goes on.

What I am going to say here is all the device transmit the readings (Latitude and Longitude) for every 1 minte to my IP but when i get the Signal from a device I will get only from device 1 after few 5 to 6 minutes Device 2 then 3 .

My problem is that my application is losing the packets. This means when my application is receiving data from Device 17 the application is receiving the last 5 to 6 minutes readings but it has lost the readings from past 10 to 30 minutes.

How can I get the signal from all the devices parallely to same port using one socket?

This is the code I have implemented:

```
Thread th_main, th_sub;
bool bool_Start_subTH;
Socket Socket_Client;
TcpListener objListener;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool_Start_subTH=false;
    th_main = new Thread(GetDataFromClient);
    th_main.Start();
 }

void GetDataFromClient()
{
    objListener = new TcpListener(5000);
    objListener.Start();
    while (th_main.IsAlive)
    {
        Socket_Client= objListener.AcceptSocket();
        if(!bool_Start_subTH)
        { 
            th_sub=new Thread (SubFunctionThread);
            th_sub.start();
            bool_Start_subTH=false;
        }
    }
 }

void SubFunctionThread()
{
    while(th_sub.IsAlive)
    {
        if(Socket_Client.Avilable>0)
        {
            byte[] something = new byte[Socket_Client.Available];
            Socket_Client.Receive(something);
            string strmessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(something);
            Listbox1.Items.Add( strmessage);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start a receiver thread for each connected client. And don't add each message to the UI in the receiver thread because this can be the problem why the code can't follow.

Comment: Could you change you communication protocole?I think in case of having 17 devices,tcp,which requires an established connection for each device,maybe is not very convenient. I have developed this project with UDP without problem.Furthermore, I agree with Wouter too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the thread which deals with the clients, it stay in a loop eating all the CPU. You should avoid the Available and read the socket directly (in fact that's all you suppose to do, wait until something comes in), making it to stop until some data gets in. Also, you may change

```
 if (Socket_Client.Avilable > 0)
```

by

```
if (Socket_Client.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
```

in case you need to check something once in a while, for example the thread is not alive.